# How to import single CSV file with more than one table to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, node.js, excel, csv, phpmyadmin

I've just found that I can import a CSV file to MySQL table. I tried it on phpMyAdmin, but I also found out that by importing a CSV file, its columns need to match the mysql database table you are importing to. This means one CSV file equals one table only in the SQL database, correct me if I'm wrong though.

The problem is the `employee` table I'm inserting data to, is related to other tables. There's also the `rolemap` table where when every employee is inserted in the employee table, the rolemap table also creates a new row for that new employee(only inserts the employee_id generated by the employee table, then the role of the user if admin or not).

The question is can I achieve this logic, by importing a CSV file in phpMyAdmin or any database manager? I'm thinking that maybe there will be some formatting that needs to be done in the CSV file in order to import to different tables in the database. Or is this not possible, that I need to parse the CSV file in a backend and handle how to insert it to each respective table in the database?

Comment: 'The question is can I achieve this logic, by importing a CSV file in phpMyAdmin or any database manager? ' - No , I suggest you import to a staging table and then do the needful.

Comment: @P.Salmon, yeah I'm still researching and found out about the staging table. Still not clear to me though, so the next step after importing to the staging table, I'll have to run SQL script in phpMyAdmin against the staging table in order to distribute the data to separate tables accordingly?